# Proof that the exists a bijective function

Tags: functions

$S$ be a set. Consider the set of all functions from $S$ into $\{0,1\}$.

The set is $2^S$

How do I proof that there exists a bijective function from $P(S)$ to $2^S$

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you were describing a subset of S to a friend.

But for some reason you can't just write down that subset. Instead, your friend goes through each element of S and asks you at each element - is this is element in the subset? You get to tell him only yes or no. Surely you can describe your subset in this way.

Do you see the connection?